# Using Beep sound on keystroke C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, event-handling, operator-overloading

So I want to help a friend with a project and he needed something to make a sound on each keystroke. He reads data as integer values using std::cin and I wonder if it's in any way possible to make a function which will not modify the rest of his project using multi threading or overloading somehow the istream >> operator so it would make a beep sound on each key press.
I tried this and I understand that the overloading concept is probably bad and that I probably don't understand how multi threading works but could you recommand some articles so I can learn to solve this kind of problem?Maybe event handling in c++ but I didn't find anything general, just event handling in game frameworks. Maybe some tips?
Here's my excuse of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


//compile error very bad
istream& operator>>(istream& in, int& n)
{
    int i=0;
    char c;
    string nr;
    nr.resize(30);
    do{
        c = getch();
        if(c >= '0' && c<= '9' && i < 30)
        {
            cout<<c;
            Beep(1000, 10);
            nr[i++] = c;
        }
        if(c == '\b')
        {
            i--;
            cout<<"\b \b";
        }
    }while(int(c) != 13);

    //maybe like this and return void?
    n = stoi(nr);

    //or like this? even tho makes no sense to me that it would work?
    return  in>>stoi(nr);
}

void playBeep()
{
    while(getch())
    {
        Beep(1000, 10);
    }
}


int main()
{
    //maybe this?
    thred t(playBeep);
    t.join();

    //or this with the operator overload somehow?
    int arr[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the program meant to run as a console app? Windows does not inform console apps about keystroke events.  If you want the program to be notified of each individual keystroke, then you will have to write some kind of a GUI app.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yeah it was intended to run on console, so my only option would be to replace all "cin >> data" with some custom made function?

Comment: @Willneeh yes, you have to read in non blocking mode

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Windows programming, but I don't think it's that simple. I don't have a lot of experience developing for Windows, but if I was in your shoes,  I'd be looking for some GUI framework that has a widget that emulates a Windows console, and then I'd look for a way to hook a keypress handler in to that widget that allows your program to be notified of the keystrokes, but without preventing the widget from also handling them in its own way.

Comment: @bruno's way might be easier, I didn't think of that.  But, if you do it his way, you'll have to write your own line editor.

Comment: @SolomonSlow we have nothing for nothing :-)

Comment: You can read console events directly but then you probably have to ditch the c++ parts of the input stream handling and do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

[`PeekConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput) can be used to peek at stdin from another thread. You will probably miss some events because there is no synchronization with your main thread. This should be regarded as a hack but might work well enough for your needs.

If you are willing to ditch the C/C++ stdin APIs then you can read the low-level Win32 console input events with `ReadConsoleInput` or the text input with `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole`.